# How to design my own keras layer?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I am implementing the paper [Perceptual GAN for small object detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05274). The design is described by the picture given below. I need to design my own keras layer. I have described my code below:
[image]

The user defined keras layer should consist of the following steps:

```
 model=VGG16() #loading pretrained VGG16 model
 intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, output=[model.layers[1].output, model.layers[5].output])
 y=layers.Conv2D(9,1,padding='SAME')(intermediate_layer_model.output[0])
 y=layers.Conv2D(1,1,padding='SAME')(y)
 output=residualblock(y)
 output1=roipooling(intermediate_layer.output[1],rois)
 add(output,output1)
```

I donot know **how to code my own keras layer performing the above steps**. Can anyone help me with the coding?

Comment: What is your layer supposed to do? Please provide some information

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: @Leevo I have included it in the question itself under the heading **The user defined keras layer should consist of the following steps:** and it is also given in the figure above.

Comment: @ignatius I followed the blog but couldn't code it out. So I asked for help here

Comment: Broad questions receives broad answers … I suggest to post your code (your custom keras code) with information about why it is not working and let's see what the community can do to help you… but there are Little chances you'll get your code made by some else...

Comment: I have coded all the inner functionalities of the generator network(as given in the diagram) but I could not predict from the generator network as they are not layers. So I thought of an alternative to define my own keras layers with this functionalities but I couldn't understand the parameters in [https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) and therefore couldn't code it out. It seems to be tensorflow/theano backend approach and I have always worked with keras frontend and not really cared about the backend platform.

Comment: Offcourse I will not get it all sorted out by someone else but it will initiate the work and give a push towards what I am looking for. If you can understand me!!